# .Net Remoting long running processes timeout

Tags: c#, remoting

We have a system set up where several services are talking to each other using .Net Remoting. Moving to WCF is not an option right now.

We are experiencing an issue where a client is initiating an operation on the server that takes a really long time because it is doing a lot of work. During the middle of this operation, the server thread suddenly dies and throws a RemotingException with an underlying IOException with the message:

```
"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
```

We have not messed with any timeouts ourselves. Does .Net Remoting have a default timeout value that will terminate the server thread if it takes too long?

In the meantime, we are having the remoting call spawn another thread to do the work and return immediately. Are there other options?